# Android | Fresco / FrescoLib + Azure

Tags: android, azure, azure-storage, fresco

I'm hosting my application in azure (Web service + file storage service).

I wish to use Fresco (SimpleDraweeView) in my application, the problem is that i can not give a direct url to the user, as the storage in azure is private.

The only thing i can do is to get the image as byte array (using my web service) and foward this byte array back to the android client.

How can one use simpledraweeview with a byte array instead of a direct link?

I have tried to set an endpoint in my webservice where the user is giving me the image id and the endpoint returns back the byte array, i have tried to use this endpoint as the url for the simpledraweeview.setImageUrl method but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, per my experience, it sounds like you need to create a web app as proxy service to access and response the image hosted on Azure File Storgae back to andoird.

Assumption that you are a Java Web developer, I think the simple way is that you can [create a Java web app in Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-java-get-started/), then create a Java servlet for the Java web app and refer to the article [How to use File Storage from Java](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-java-how-to-use-file-storage/#how-to-download-a-file) to download the image to pipe the stream to http servlet response, please see the sample code below.

```
private static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
                    "AccountName=your_storage_account_name;" +
                    "AccountKey=your_storage_account_key";
private CloudFileClient fileClient;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public PipeStream4FileStorage() {
    super();
    try {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
        fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String dirName = request.getParameter("dir");
    String fileName = request.getParameter("file");
    OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        // Get a reference to the file share
        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference("sampleshare");
        //Get a reference to the root directory for the share.
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
        //Get a reference to the directory that contains the file
        CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(dirName);
        //Get a reference to the file you want to download
        CloudFile file = sampleDir.getFileReference(fileName);
        //Write the stream of the file to the httpServletResponse.
        file.download(outStream);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (StorageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note, please see the javadoc for the key function [`download(OutputStream outStream)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/file/CloudFile.html#download(java.io.OutputStream)).

Then, you just need to set the image url for SimpleDraweeView like below.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://<your-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/<servlet-url-mapping-name>?dir=<dir-name>&file=<file-name>");
SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
draweeView.setImageURI(uri);
```

Comment: I had to return the file with it's appropriate content-type (ie image/jpeg) and it worked! thanks :)